# OCaml identify type

Tags: types, ocaml

i am currently learning OCaml. I have some basic knowledge in other functional languages like Haskell, so it's not all new for me.
[Here](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~dpw/courses/cos326-12/precepts/precept01.ml) are some tasks (the task, here, is to replace the question marks with the fitting types.) that I am trying to solve. I don't get 2c :

```
let forever (x : ??) : ?? =
  forever forever
;;
```

First it should be `let rec forever`, right?

I thought about `unit` but my compiler says that this is not valid OCaml. Do you have any hints for me? What I think is that it should not be valid with any type, but who knows, maybe I am missing any OCaml secrets.

Comment: Don't know why i got the downvote. Better comment what you dislike on my question.

Comment: You should improve your question. The formatting of your code is bad, `Let` is not a keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `forever` needs to be declared as recursive in OCaml. So you have

```
let rec forever x = forever forever
```

The function `forever` takes one argument. Because of the expression `forever forever` you know that the type of the argument is the same as the type of `forever` itself.

There are very few types for which this will be the case. Certainly the type of the argument of `forever` must be a function type at the very least.

Since `forever` accepts the type that it has itself, its type is recursive. In many functional languages, such types aren't supported. But you can use them in OCaml if you specify `-rectypes` on the command line.

So you might try this:

```
$ ocaml -rectypes
# let rec forever x = forever forever;;
```

OCaml will tell you the type that it infers for `forever`.

**Update**

It's worth pointing out that these are interesting corners of the OCaml type system, and type theory in general. But you're not going to see types (or code) like this in practice.

You can read about recursive types in Chapters 20 and 21 of Pierce, *Types and Programming Languages*.

Comment: That worked. Thank's :) rectype wasn't explained in the previous chapters. But i will google that to get the context. But what isn't 100% clear to me. forever has the type 'a -> 'b as 'a. It isn't clear to me what the 'as' means. And much more important for me, the function want's some type 'a as parameter, so in "function function", the first call get's the function itself as a parameter, but this function didn't get anything as parameter. How do i have to understand this? It is like the first "forever" is a call to the function and the parameter is like a function pointer as parameter?

Comment: It's hard to answer new questions in this comment area, there's no room. Functions in OCaml (and other FP langs) are first class values. So you can pass them to functions, etc. That's all that's going on. It's not helpful to think of function pointers, that's a low level idea. But `forever` is just one kind of value, yes.

Comment: That is what i meant. I didn't had better words to explain what i thought. I have some experience with other functional languages so i knew the concept of first class functions etc. Thank you very much for helping me out :)

Comment: @Schorsch `'a -> 'b as 'a` means “alpha is the type of a function which takes a value of type alpha returning a value of type beta,” e.g. forever could also be written as `type t = t -> 'b;; let forever : t = fun (x : t) -> forever forever`

Comment: I would say that a recursive type describes a set of types in the same sense that a parametric polymorphic type does. ('a -> 'b) as 'a actually means the set of types that can be produced by substituing 'a by 'a -> 'b in ('a -> 'b) as 'a,The problem arises from the fact that to type forever you need 'a to be equal to 'a -> 'b which entails an infintie number of solutions for alpha but with the recursive type you can describe in a finite way the inifinte number of  solutions for this equation.